# Inconsistent CSS 100vh property with different browsers and operating systems

Tags: html, css

I'm making a [patatap.com](https://patatap.com) website clone for learning purposes. I want the site to take exactly 100% of the available screen height. There is no more content so no scrolling is needed. I'm using the 100vh CSS property for this:

```
body, html {
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This is the current version of the website:
http://patatap-clone.hexagonwebdev.vxm.pl/ (press any letter or number on keyboard to use it's functionality).

It is OK on Windows 7 on Internet Explorer and Firefox, but on Chrome (latest version - 70.0.3538.102) the site takes more than full screen and I can scroll down a bit. 
It is bad on Ubuntu - on Chromium and Firefox around 30% of site is not visible (this laptop has smaller resolution).

Is there a better way to achieve the "non-scrolling" and 100% height goal? I have tried max-height: 100% and !important properties but that did not help.

Comment: All I'm seeing on your site is a black container. Is there more to it?

Comment: Yes there is, press any key on keyboard (letter or a number), it will create a circle/square with sound and some simple animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content will force just about anything to get bigger if you haven't set `overflow` properties. Conversely, setting `max-height` doesn't make the content bigger so the height will be the content height up to the max-height.

Finally, try not to set the height of the body/html tags. Those are "special" tags that don't function the same way other elements do.

Instead, create a container that is the full size of the screen.

```
/* normal div */
.container {
  display:block;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: black;
}

/* or absolutely positioned div */
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bryce, overflow: hidden solved the case. Thanks a lot for your help!